# While loading Multiple angular Ui-Grids on a page browser freezes

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have grids placed under accordion control. When there are more than 5 grids loading on the same page the browser freezes for a noticeable amount of time.
Does anyone has come across the same issue?

Comment: Are you sure its not because of the too many http calls for the 5 grids?

Comment: I tried commenting out the http calls and just load the empty grids. Still the browser freezes. And also once the grids are loaded after a while, scrolling through the page creates a lag. Especially in IE11.

Comment: Go to Performance tab from the page inspector, start recording and reload the page, record upto the time you feel the lag, stop recording and it will show up a timeline and there you will be able to see which one takes the most time. Sometimes, if you are calling controller functions from cellTemplates and doing a lot of stuff there, it can ofcourse lag. Are there any cases like that ?